# monitors.xml not found

Tags: 22.04, display-resolution, system-settings

I have changed the display settings in Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. In particular, I have changed the scaling (from 100% and 300%) and rotated to portrait mode. Now, I would like to also adapt the log in screen. To do this, I tried `sudo cp ~/.config/monitors.xml /var/lib/gdm3/.config/`.

Unfortunately, `~/.config/monitors.xml` does not exist. I did not find any `monitors.xml` file on my system.

Why is this the case?

Comment: When you apply the settings it should create the `monitors.xml` file for you in the `~/.config` directory.  Might want to adjust the settings a bit then set them back and apply it.  https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2022/11/login-screen-external-monitor-ubuntu/

Comment: @Terrance The settings are stored (i.e., rotation persists also after reboot) but no monitors.xml file was created. I also tried to change settings.

Comment: Ah, I am wondering if you are using Wayland or XOrg.  The output of `echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE` should tell you.  I haven't messed with it enough, but it might be that Wayland doesn't support creating the monitors.xml file.

Comment: try making a change in the monitor setting and then an apply button should appear click on it and it should create/update an monitors.xml file. I had the same issue on 20.04